# How to hiding toolbar?

Tags: cocoa, toolbar

I dragged an UItoolbar to the window in IB, I want it disappear when I click a button.
This is the methond -

```
-(IBAction)hiding:(id)sender{
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO]; }
```

but nothing happen...

can you help me fix it?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UINavigationController's `setToolbarHidden:animated:` affects the UIToolbar that is built into the navigation controller. You've added a UIToolbar on your own, so that method won't affect it. To affect that one, you'll have to get a pointer to it somehow (e.g. attach it to an IBOutlet in IB) and then use its `hidden` property.